# Temp tables in SQL Server 2005 not automatically dropped

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm troubleshooting a nasty stored procedure and noticed that after running it, and I have closed my session, lots of temp tables are still left in tempdb. They have names like the following:

```
#000E262B
#002334C4
#004E1D4D
#00583EEE
#00783A7F
#00832777
#00CD403A
#00E24ED3
#00F75D6C
```

If I run this code:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#000E262B') is null   
print 'Does NOT exist!'
```

I get:

```
Does NOT exist!
```

If I do:

```
use tempdb
go
drop TABLE #000E262B
```

I get an error:

```
Msg 3701, Level 11, State 5, Line 1
Cannot drop the table '#000E262B', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
```

I am connected to SQL Server as sysadmin. Using SP3 64-bit. I currently have over 1100 of these tables in tempdb, and I can't get rid of them. There are no other users on the database server.

Stopping and starting SQL Server is not an option in my case.

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you seeing that the tables still exist then?

Comment: use tempdb
go
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic456599-149-1.aspx

If temp tables or table variables are frequently used then, instead of dropping them, SQL just 'truncates' them, leaving the definition. It saves the effort of recreating the table next time it's needed.

Comment: Great thanks - so that forum post confirmed to me that the tables are a result of table varialbes and the optimizer has decided to keep them as they're referenced often. I would still like to get rid of them to eliminate a performance problem I have.

Comment: Dropping a table or letting it go out of scope does not actually drop it immediately.  Your batch knows that you've dropped it, so you can no longer reference it, but it's still there.  There is a background process that handles the actual dropping process.  Maybe watch the counter "Temp Tables for Destruction" to see if this really is a source of your performance problem.  You can find details about this under the Monitoring and Troubleshooting section (lots of scrolling) : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966545.aspx#EDAA

Comment: Thanks Aaron. 24 hours later the same number of tables are in tempdb, however I have dropped all user connections to the database server. I checked the performance counters from that excellent article you posted, and the number of Temp Tables for Destruction has been zero for over twelve hours.

Answer (score 0):

Tables created with the # prefix are only available to the current connection. Therefore any new connection you create will not be able to see them and therefore not be able to drop them.

How can you tell that they still exist? What command are you running to find this out?

Is the connection that created them closed properly? If not then this may be why they still exist.

Comment: Thanks Robin - but I'm the only user on this database instance. The connection that created them has been disconnected.

Comment: Can you state how you can see that these tables are still there? Is this using sp_tables? SELECT * FROM sysobjects?